# How to add build number and date from github in ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, github, capistrano, build-numbers

How can you automatically import the latest github commit number from github?

The goal would be to have that number visible on your webpage footer like SO does with date.

**Whats the structure**:

I have a production branch which is deployed using Capistrano. I want to show the latest github commit number, with the date when it was deployed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you use gem `settingslogic` for app settings, put this in your initializers:

```
git_log = `git log -1 --pretty="format:%H %ci"`
if git_log =~ /^([\d\w]+?)\s(.+)$/
  Settings[:git_revision] = $1
  Settings[:git_update]   = $2.strip
end
```

You will have last git commit SHA in `Settings.git_revision` and commit date in `Settings.git_update`.

Additionally you can get last tag:

```
git_tag = `git describe --tags --abbrev=0`
Settings[:git_tag] = git_tag.strip if git_tag
```

It will be available in `Settings.git_tag`.

**Update:**

I released a small ruby gem [git-revision](https://github.com/NARKOZ/git-revision#readme). With it you can simply do:

```
"commit: #{Git::Revision.commit} date: #{Git::Revision.date}"
```

Answer (score 0):

As possible solution you can to see at (universal) solution with [git smudge|clean filters](http://progit.org/book/ch7-2.html) (read "Keyword Expansion" part)